# I want to maximise my function over a particular domain

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, maximum

I have tried NMaximise. But I am getting an error always. Even if my command is correct. My function is

```
Cos[π E^x]
```

and I want to maximise it over the range (-3,3)

Comment: `NMaximize[Cos[Pi*E^x], x]`

Comment: Make a plot of your function to convince yourself that there are multiple maxima. The standard way to solve this, is to set the derivative to zero. This gives you maxima as well as minima:  Solve[{D[Cos[Pi Exp[x]], x] == 0, -3 <= x <= 3}, x]

Comment: `NMaximize[{Cos[Pi*E^x], -3 < x < 3}, x]`

Comment: a typo :   `NMaximize` instead of `NMaximise`

Answer (score 1):

Plot[Cos[π*E^x], {x, -3, 3}]

[image]

There is no unique maximum on the intervall (-3,3) for Cos(πe^x). The function oscillates increasingly rapidly the larger x gets. There many maxima at {x,1}.

The equation is 2 π n == π Exp[x] for natural positive n and π Exp[3] is upper limit.

```
Table[Solve[2 \[Pi] n == \[Pi] Exp[x], x, Reals], {n, 1, 10}]
```

(* {{{x -> Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png)}}, {{x -> 2 Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png)}}, {{x -> Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png) + Log[3]}}, {{x ->
3 Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png)}}, {{x -> Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png) + Log[5]}}, {{x ->
2 Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png) + Log[3]}}, {{x -> Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png) + Log[7]}}, {{x ->
4 Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png)}}, {{x -> Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png) + 2 Log[3]}}, {{x ->
2 Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png) + Log[5]}}}  *)

2 Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49oss.png) + Log[5] approx. 2.99573 < 3

So there 10 maxima in the interval (-3,3).

```
Plot[Cos[\[Pi]*E^x], {x, -3, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], 
   Point[MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {data, Array[1 &, {10}]}]]}]
```

[image: plot of the maxima]

`NMaximize` finds only one value. That is insufficient. But on the proper selected interval in can find numerical unique maxima:

```
Table[NMaximize[{Cos[Pi*E^x], Log[2 n] < x < Log[2 n + 1]}, x], {n, 1,
   10}]
```

(* {{1., {x -> 0.693147}}, {1., {x -> 1.38629}}, {1., {x ->
1.79176}}, {1., {x -> 2.07944}}, {1., {x -> 2.30259}}, {1., {x ->
2.48491}}, {1., {x -> 2.63906}}, {1., {x -> 2.77259}}, {1., {x ->
2.89037}}, {1., {x -> 2.99573}}}  *)

Answer (score 1):

All the maximums of a smooth function `Cos[Pi*E^x]` on an interval `x>-3,x<3` can be found in such a way:

```
Reduce[{D[Cos[Pi*E^x], x] == 0,D[Cos[Pi*E^x], {x, 2}] < 0, -3 < x < 3}, x]
```

> `x==Log[2]||x==2 Log[2]||x==3 Log[2]||x==4 Log[2]||x==Log[2]+Log[3]||x==2 Log[2]+Log[3]||x==Log[2]+2 Log[3]||x==Log[2]+Log[5]||x==2 Log[2]+Log[5]||x==Log[2]+Log[7]`

Another way is as follows.

```
ResourceFunction["StationaryPoints"][{Cos[Pi*E^x], -3 < x && x < 3}, {x}]
```

> `<|"Minima" -> {{-1, {x -> 0}}, {-1, {x -> Log[3]}}, {-1, {x ->  2 Log[3]}}, {-1, {x -> Log[5]}}, {-1, {x ->  Log[3] + Log[5]}}, {-1, {x -> Log[7]}}, {-1, {x ->  Log[11]}}, {-1, {x -> Log[13]}}, {-1, {x ->  Log[17]}}, {-1, {x -> Log[19]}}},  "Maxima" -> {{1, {x -> Log[2]}}, {1, {x -> 2 Log[2]}}, {1, {x ->  3 Log[2]}}, {1, {x -> 4 Log[2]}}, {1, {x ->  Log[2] + Log[3]}}, {1, {x -> 2 Log[2] + Log[3]}}, {1, {x ->  Log[2] + 2 Log[3]}}, {1, {x -> Log[2] + Log[5]}}, {1, {x ->  2 Log[2] + Log[5]}}, {1, {x -> Log[2] + Log[7]}}}|>`

Answer (score 0):

```
NMaximize[{Cos[Pi*E^x], -3 < x < 3}, x]
```

> `{1., {x -> 1.38629}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Maximize[{Cos[π E^x], -3 <= x <= 3}, x]
```

Even has a symbolic solution.

> {1, {x -> Log[2] + Log[5]}}

Comment: Thankyou so much